# Why is R not displaying the f-values for two way anova?

Tags: r, anova

I have three variables:

- Number of house sales
- Month (in couples)
- Region of a city (N-W-E-S)

and I want to create a two way anova with interaction for the variables:

```
month <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","5","5","5","5","6","6","6","6")
region <-c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4")
sales <-c(85, 107,61, 22, 40, 65, 58,51,60,41,45,27,15,30,68,63,28,3,57,12,36,21,10,16)

data <- cbind(sales, month, region)
data <- as.data.frame(data)

mod.aov <- aov(sales ~ month*region, data = data)
summary(mod.aov)
```

and as you can see:

```
> summary(mod.aov)
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
month         5   6369  1273.7
region        3   1043   347.6
month:region 15   7854   523.6
```

R is not displaying the f-values for this model. Why is that?

And just related to this example, is it possible (or meaningful) to perform a linear regression model for two categorical variables as predictors with interaction between them?
Any insight would be appreciated.
Thx!

Comment: can you check you code, it should be ```data = data.frame(sales,month,region)``` you cannot cbind a character with a numeric, all will be converted to character

Answer (score 1):

You have only 1 observation per combination of month and data, you cannot estimate the effect of month:region with n=1.

```
data = data.frame(sales,month,region)
table(data$month,data$region)
   
    1 2 3 4
  1 1 1 1 1
  2 1 1 1 1
  3 1 1 1 1
  4 1 1 1 1
  5 1 1 1 1
  6 1 1 1 1
```

You can loosely interpret as , Anova is analysis of variance, and n=1 means no variance. Hence the summary is not displaying f values.

And to answer this question:

> And just related to this example, is it possible (or meaningful) to
> perform a linear regression model for two categorical variables as
> predictors with interaction between them? Any insight would be
> appreciated

Yes you can do that, for example in this case, if you would have more than 1 replicate for each month and region combination, you are basically modeling the effect of region to be different for every month.

Answer (score 0):

I read in another post that the model is saturated, as there are not enough data points for all the degrees of freedom needed for the model.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94078/why-do-i-not-get-a-p-value-from-this-anova-in-r